# user can select all structure from pg_catalog.*, but can't make a dump -s

Tags: postgresql

Given: Postgres RDS 9.3, pg_dump 9.3, RDS user (not SU)

I have:

> ```
> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation rel
> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.rel IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
> ```

When I run :

```
-bash-4.2$ pg_dump -s --section=pre-data -h hostname -d db -U not_su
```

*(tried both `--schema-only` and `--section=pre-data` in desperate hope they would differently not require a lock, but no success)*

Yet:

When I login to db with same user, I can `\dt+ rel` and see the structure, so I can see definition from pg_attributes and pg_class for this rel and all related relations...

Is there any way to overcome this limitation?.. Or I have to build DDL based on pg_catalog?.. (seems not reasonable that my user can select all structure, but can't make a structure only dump)

### Update:

I must be very unclear In my question. Here is example:

As superuser:

```
t=# create table so15(i bigserial primary key);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create user so15;
CREATE ROLE
```

As user without permissions:

```
postgres@vao-VirtualBox:~$ psql -U so15 -h localhost -d t
psql (9.6.1)

t=> \d+ so15
                                            Table "public.so15"
 Column |  Type  |                    Modifiers                     | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 i      | bigint | not null default nextval('so15_i_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "so15_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (i)
```

So I can see the structure of so15 relation without read permissions, now as same user I `pg_dump -s`:

```
postgres@vao-VirtualBox:~$ pg_dump -s -t so15 -U so15  -h localhost -d t
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation so15
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.so15 IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

Comment: Please correct a space between `-d db-U not_su` in your script.

Comment: Please check owner of table `rel`.

Answer (score 1):

### DUMP pg_catalog

Here's simple script to dump objects' structures in **pg_catalog**.

`pg_dump -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -s --table=pg_catalog.* > catalog.sql`

And the result looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE pg_authid (
    rolname name NOT NULL,
    rolsuper boolean NOT NULL,
    rolinherit boolean NOT NULL,
    rolcreaterole boolean NOT NULL,
    rolcreatedb boolean NOT NULL,
    rolcanlogin boolean NOT NULL,
    rolreplication boolean NOT NULL,
    rolbypassrls boolean NOT NULL,
    rolconnlimit integer NOT NULL,
    rolpassword text,
    rolvaliduntil timestamp with time zone
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY pg_authid REPLICA IDENTITY NOTHING;
ALTER TABLE pg_authid OWNER TO postgres;
```

### UPDATE from Vao Tsun:

From [pg_dump doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html):

> pg_dump internally executes SELECT statements. If you have problems
>   running pg_dump, make sure you are able to select information from the
>   database using, for example, [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html)

From [psql doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html)

> By default, only user-created objects are shown; supply a pattern or
>   the S modifier to include system objects.
>
> **Note**: If \d is used without a ***pattern*** argument, it is equivalent to
>   \dtvsE which will show a list of all visible tables, views, sequences
>   and foreign tables

In terms of your case  "**user without permissions**". I guess the `so15` table belongs to **public** schema. That's why `so15` user can see table structure (`\d+ so15`).

**For example**: if you login `admin` user and create *new table* on *new schema*, then login `so15` user to test ( remember to `set search_path = new_schema` before doing `\d+`). You cannot see this *new table* because of permission.

Besides, you cannot dump `so15` table due to `pg_dump` will execute `SELECT` and it needs permission on this table.

**Solution:** to dump `so15` table you should [grant privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483555/give-all-the-permissions-to-a-user-on-a-db) to `so15` user.

Comment: `-s` still requires select permissions for the relation.

Comment: sorry - I must be very unclear with my question. I updated it. Any ideas on how to workaround this limitation? I know I can select from pg_catalog. Just hoping there  is a better way